# How to use one script for diff and diff3 in Subversion?

Tags: perl, svn, diff, diff3

I have a Perl script that determines what external diff to use depending on the file's content. I would like to use it determine external diff3 also.

Which is the best method to know how my script is being called?

I was planning to catch the last three parameters, and verify if they are all files, to use the diff3 options, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner method.

Comment: What version control system? Where are the "files" coming from? What are these other parameters you speak of?

Comment: We use Subversion.  That itself is a version control system. http://subversion.tigris.com

Comment: The Subversion system uses Unix's diff and diff3 when comparing file differences by default.  When you configure it for some other application, the system sends a couple of parameters: 7 for the diff alternate and 11 for the diff3 alternate.

Comment: For more detail:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff

Comment: Copy (or symlink) the script to a different name and use `$0`